# VBA Save active email to subfolder in inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

Im stuck with problem to move active email to subfolder in inbox. 
Need to replace ("xxxx@xxx.xxx") to something as olFolderInbox or inbox, etc without type specific email adress in VBA code.

```
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolderItem As Outlook.Folder

Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolderItem = objNS.Folders.Item("xxxx@xxx.xxx").Folders.Item("tmp")

objMail.Move objMoveItem
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Exampls()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim Item As MailItem
    Set Item = ActiveExplorer.selection(1)

        Item.Move Inbox.Folders("Temp")

End Sub
```